# MEAN Stack Can't list data on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have some issue my website development. It's MEAN stack and I am going to show data on table

I've coded node.js like this.

```js
var Property = mongoose.model('Property');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId; //Have also tried Schema.Types.ObjectId, mongoose.ObjectId

// Property Routing Management

router.get('/property', function(req, res, next) {
  Property.find({}, function(err, properties) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    return res.json(properties);
  })
});
```

And this is Angular Controller.

```js
angular.module('MetronicApp').controller('EditPropertyController', [
        '$scope',         
        's_property',
        '$state', 
        '$location',
        function($scope, s_property, $state, $location) {            
            s_property.getAllProperties();
            $scope.properties = s_property.all_properties;

}]);
```

and the service

```js
angular.module('MetronicApp')
  .factory('s_property', [
    '$http',
    '$window',
    's_auth',
    function($http, $window, s_auth) {
      var service = {
        all_properties: [],
        current_property: {}
      };
      service.getAllProperties = function() {
        return $http.get('/api/v1/property').then(function(res, err) {
          service.all_properties = res.data;          
          return res.data;
        })
      }
      return service;
    }
  ]);
```

and finally HTML file.

```html
<tr class="odd gradeX" ng-repeat="property in properties">
  <td ng-bind="property.propertyAddress"></td>
  <td ng-bind="property.propertyCity"></td>
  <td ng-bind="property.status"></td>
  <td class="center" ng-bind="property.joinedDate"></td>
  <td ng-bind="property.user"></td>
</tr>
```

property colloection and required documents are successfully exist on MongoDB.

But table does not show data.
I appreciate your answers.
Regards,

Comment: Hi Neil, this is not duplicated question. Did you read this carefully?

Comment: Have you tested whether data is retrieved from the database and from the server?